# Can I increase up to 5000 points limit of feature layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have created searching functionality to using the JavaScript API and I have feature layers which has grater than 1000 points. I want to put all point of particular feature layers on map but currently, There are only 1000 or less than that displayed over there.

currently I'm using following code :

```
    layer.setMaxAllowableOffset(5000);
    layer.setDefinitionExpression(expString);
```

is there any help for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Feature( or map ) Service using arcmap ; connect to your arcgis server , locate the service and open service edit  window, in the right menu locate the  parameters and reset the value of `Maximum number of record returned by the server` it's set to 1000 by default , change it to 5000 . (greater the value is set, lower the performance of server will be )

Your feature layer now ,draws 5000 feature layer on the map ( also for queries ...).